# MySQL select records with sum greater than threshold

Tags: mysql

I need to select records based on file size listed in a MySQL database table, with a single query (no store procedures). The record set should contain all records where the sum total file size equals or if needed exceeds a specific threshold. (Example, threshold = 30, results return 3 records with file sizes equal to 10, 10, 20 or 10, 10, 10 or one record with a file size of 32)

table

```
+----+---------+-----------+
| id | user_id | fileSize  |
+----+---------+-----------+
|  1 |       1 |      9319 |
|  2 |       1 |     51683 |
|  3 |       1 |     19776 |
|  4 |       1 |    395890 |
|  5 |       1 |      7132 |
|  6 |       1 |     97656 |
|  7 |       1 |      9798 |
|  9 |       1 |     16096 |
| 10 |       1 |    113910 |
| 11 |       1 |    160037 |
+----+---------+-----------+
```

After researching and trying a number of different solutions the best query that I have come up with looks like this:

```
SELECT f1.user_id, f1.id AS file_id, f1.fileSize, SUM(f2.fileSize) AS totalSum
FROM files AS f1 
INNER JOIN files AS f2 ON f1.id >= f2.id 
WHERE f1.user_id = 1
GROUP BY f1.id 
HAVING totalSum <= 350000;
```

Example results

```
+---------+---------+-----------+----------+
| user_id | file_id |  fileSize | totalSum |
+---------+---------+-----------+----------+
|       1 |       1 |      9319 |     9319 |
|       1 |       2 |     51683 |    61002 |
|       1 |       3 |     19776 |    80778 |
+---------+---------+-----------+----------+
```

Desired results

```
+---------+---------+-----------+----------+
| user_id | file_id |  fileSize | totalSum |
+---------+---------+-----------+----------+
|       1 |       1 |      9319 |     9319 |
|       1 |       2 |     51683 |    61002 |
|       1 |       3 |     19776 |    80778 |
|       1 |       4 |    395890 |   476668 |
+---------+---------+-----------+----------+
```

Or

```
+---------+---------+-----------+----------+
| user_id | file_id |  fileSize | totalSum |
+---------+---------+-----------+----------+
|       1 |       3 |    395890 |   395890 |
+---------+---------+-----------+----------+
```

What isn't working with the query above is that the threshold will never be met, as it is based on HAVING lesser than the threshold (greater than just returns crazy amounts of records well above the threshold). Also, if there are any records in the set that have a file size exceeding the threshold, the query result sometimes returns empty. Ideal results would meet or slightly exceed the threshold and may contain many records or a single record if the single file size matched or exceeded the threshold.

Any help would be appreciated. I think this is the first time I have posted a question online in about five years. Seriously, been stuck on this for a week. ~ Thx

Comment: `slightly exceed` I suppose you need some kind of fuzzy logic here, anyway - provide results of the query and expected ones for posted sample data

Comment: Well, I didn't know how to say what I meant. "Keep selecting until the sum is greater than or equal to the threshold." would be more appropriate. Will provide sample results shortly.

Comment: I'd suggest doing this in your application code, since you're going to retreive all the rows anyway.

Comment: something like this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/while.html ?

Comment: Right, but how do you use WHILE syntax in a single query? If stored procedures were to be used, WHILE would be the go to for sure. Perhaps Fox is correct, simply select * records for the user and filter in the application code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to be fitted for a UNION resultset. So you have to get 2 queries (one for each "criteria") and join their result using union.

First query would become:

```
SELECT f1.user_id, f1.id AS file_id, SUM(f1.fileSize) AS totalSum
FROM files AS f1 
WHERE f1.user_id = 1
GROUP BY f1.id 
HAVING totalSum <= 350000;
```

Now you need the query that select if size is too big:

```
SELECT f1.user_id, f1.id AS file_id, MAX(f1.fileSize) AS max
FROM files AS f1 
WHERE f1.user_id = 1
GROUP BY f1.id 
HAVING max >= 350000;
```

Next you want to combine them in a single query. Since both have the same fields you can simply "union" the result

```
SELECT f1.user_id, f1.id AS file_id, SUM(f1.fileSize) AS totalSum
FROM files AS f1 
WHERE f1.user_id = 1
GROUP BY f1.id 
HAVING totalSum <= 350000
UNION
SELECT f1.user_id, f1.id AS file_id, MAX(f1.fileSize) AS max
FROM files AS f1 
WHERE f1.user_id = 1
GROUP BY f1.id 
HAVING max >= 350000;
```

PS: You had "ON f1.id >= f2.id" as join criteria, not sure why the > that would be very case-specific :)

Comment: I think some condition may be reverse, but you can tweak each criteria to match what you need. Also just think that if any files exceed a threshold, the sum of the files will also break that threshold so it may not be worth checking the two criteria unless the threshold isn't the same :)