# Get rows from table whose sum is less than value

Tags: mysql, sum, mariadb, cumulative-sum, mysql-5.7

Consider I have the following rows in the table

```
|  id |   user_id   |  amount |      date      |
------------------------------------------------
|  1  |     1       |  100    |   2019-09-30   |
------------------------------------------------
|  2  |     2       |  100    |   2019-09-30   |
------------------------------------------------
|  3  |     1       |  100    |   2019-09-30   |
------------------------------------------------
|  4  |     3       |  100    |   2019-10-01   |
------------------------------------------------
|  5  |     1       |  75     |   2019-10-01   |
------------------------------------------------
|  6  |     3       |  100    |   2019-10-01   |
------------------------------------------------
|  7  |     1       |  35     |   2019-10-01   |
------------------------------------------------
```

I am trying find a way to get all the rows with `user_id = 1` where the `sum(amount) < 300` and `date <= '2019-10-01'`.

What I am trying to do is to only process records that meet a certain threshold sum. I am not quite sure where to start.

**Expected Result**

```
|  id |   user_id   |  amount |      date      |
------------------------------------------------
|  1  |     1       |  100    |   2019-09-30   |
------------------------------------------------
|  3  |     1       |  100    |   2019-09-30   |
------------------------------------------------
|  5  |     1       |   75    |   2019-10-01   |
------------------------------------------------
```

Here is what I have tried so far

```sql
SELECT id, SUM(amount) as total_sum 
   FROM table 
   WHERE date <= '2019-10-01' AND user_id = 1
     ORDER BY date ASC
   HAVING total_sum <= 300
```

I don't get the desired output based on the above query.

MySQL Version currently using: 5.7.25

I did look at this question [MySQL select records with sum greater than threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29154122/mysql-select-records-with-sum-greater-than-threshold) assuming they are trying to do the same thing, but this isn't what I am looking at

Comment: In your expected output, you are getting a row corresponding to 1 October, but your condition is date < 1 October. Also `date < '2019-09-31'` - there is no such thing as 31 Sept. Fix the problem statement pls. Also, what is your MySQL server version ? Run `SELECT Version();`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, thanks for noticing it. I did add more rows to that data, but missed updating the problem statement. I have added the version as well.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255908/in-sql-find-the-combination-of-rows-whose-sum-add-up-to-a-specific-amount-or-am

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 3):

It is a Rolling Sum problem. In MySQL 8.0.2 and above, you can solve this using [Window functions with Frames](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html). In older versions, we can do the same using User-defined Session variables.

- We first calculate the rolling sum using [Session variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html).
- Then, use the result-set in a [Derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), and find the id where total sum crosses the "barrier" of 300. Barrier is reached when the New rolling Sum is greater than 300. We set the barrier value to 1 at this point, 0 for rows before it, and 2 and more, for the rows afterwards.
- We will only consider the rows where barrier is 0.

Try (works for all MySQL versions):

**Query #1**

```
SELECT dt.id, 
       dt.user_id, 
       dt.amount, 
       dt.date
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    t.id, 
    t.user_id, 
    t.amount, 
    t.date, 
    @barrier := CASE
                  WHEN 
                       (@tot_qty := @tot_qty + t.amount) > 300
                  THEN (@barrier + 1)
                  ELSE 0
                END AS barrier 
  FROM 
    your_table AS t 
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @tot_qty := 0, 
                     @barrier := 0) AS user_init
    WHERE t.user_id = 1 
        AND t.date <= '2019-10-01' 
  ORDER BY t.user_id, t.date, t.id
) AS dt 
WHERE dt.barrier = 0 
ORDER BY dt.user_id, dt.date, dt.id;
```

**Result**

```
| id  | user_id | amount | date       |
| --- | ------- | ------ | ---------- |
| 1   | 1       | 100    | 2019-09-30 |
| 3   | 1       | 100    | 2019-09-30 |
| 5   | 1       | 75     | 2019-10-01 |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/svmyjqaqBuNECdny4u3EmB/0)

Comment: thanks for the answer, appreciate it. How would the performance of this query be? Do we need to add indexes on any columns considering this query? This table receives almost 50k records a day and actual rows retrieved by this query may be about 150+ per user.

Comment: @Abishek Indexes depend on your `WHERE` conditions. For example, in the present query, where you are filtering for a specific user and date range, you will need a composite index: `(user_id, date)`. Order of the columns is important here. Regarding general performance, this query will have similar performance as the Window functions technique; and I consider it quite good for older versions of MySQL.

Comment: The same issue applies to this query as well. If I set the threshold limit to 180, it just returns row number 1 instead of 1st and the 5th row.

Comment: Not sure if there was any miscommunication. My problem statement was "I am trying find a way to get all the rows with `user_id = ?` where the `sum(amount) < ?` and `date <= '?'`"

Comment: @Abishek so in original problem, why wouldn't 100, 75, 35 come ? Check this modified fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/svmyjqaqBuNECdny4u3EmB/5  It seems you want to have various permutations irrespective of date order; if this is the case, this is very very difficult to do in SQL. SQL is not made to solve such scenarios.

Comment: In the original problem, `user_id=1` has rows (1,3,5,7) and the sum of all 4 rows will exceed `300`, so only the rows 1,3,5 would be returned.

Comment: @Abishek Similarly, when you consider only upto 180: Sum of row 1 and 3 is 200, which cross 180, and that is why only row 1 is considered. Now, if I understand correctly, your requirement is to consider row 5 because it row 1 + row 5 satisfies the `< 180` condition. But that basically means trying different combinations and finding the one which is closest to 180 (input). That is not doable in SQL. You will have to do this in application code like C++, Java, PHP etc

Comment: OK, I was hoping to see if there was a way to do it in mysql using the database resources instead of having to  get all the relevant data and loop through them to get the desired result.

Comment: @Abishek you may do it in some stored procedure. But at the end of the day, it will be a loop and then some if else checks to see which one suits the best. I will think on it further; and update you if I find something

Comment: Sounds good. I really appreciate the effort and getting back to me this soon. Thanks a lot

Comment: do let me know here if you had a chance to come up with a stored proc solution to this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: any chance you were able to find a solution using a stored proc?

Comment: @Abishek No I haven't had time to work on it; it's complicated.

Comment: No problem. Thanks. Appreciate your reply

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like to use Session Variables (some experienced SO users dislike them vehemently), you can utilize a technique based on "Self-Join" and then use `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` to filter out.

General idea is that we left join to get previous rows for the specific user_id, and then aggregate to get the rolling sum, and then filtering using Having clause.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
  t1.* 
FROM 
  your_table AS t1 
LEFT JOIN your_table AS t2 
  ON t2.user_id = t1.user_id 
     AND t2.date <= t1.date 
     AND t2.id <= t1.id 
WHERE t1.user_id = 1 
  AND t1.date <= '2019-10-31'
GROUP BY t1.user_id, t1.date, t1.id, t1.amount
HAVING COALESCE(SUM(t2.amount),0) < 300;
```

**Result**

```
| id  | user_id | amount | date       |
| --- | ------- | ------ | ---------- |
| 1   | 1       | 100    | 2019-09-30 |
| 3   | 1       | 100    | 2019-09-30 |
| 5   | 1       | 75     | 2019-10-01 |
```

[**View on DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/svmyjqaqBuNECdny4u3EmB/2)

You can benchmark both the approaches and decide which one is suitable.

For this query, you will need the composite index: `(user_id, date)`

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate spending time in adding another answer to this question. Good to know I can do this without the session variables. I am gonna look into both and see which works better from a performance perspective.

Comment: @Abishek you are welcome. Do let know which worked better; or both good; or both bad. If both bad, maybe we can work out more techniques, but I am putting my bet on the Session Variables one

Comment: I do see an issue this query is causing with what it returns on the result. With the `HAVING` clause set to `< 300`, it returns the correct result. But if I change the `HAVING` clause to `< 180` it returns an incorrect result. It should show 2 rows, with the amounts 100, 75, but it returns only 1 row. Here is the DB Fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/svmyjqaqBuNECdny4u3EmB/4

Comment: @Abishek there is no issue in the query. Check the input data carefully. There are two rows for `user_id = 1` on `2019-09-30` having value equal to `100`. Check the `id` values: 1,2 . So, total of them = 100 + 100 = 200 already crosses the 180 barrier, before reaching the row having value 75.

Comment: but there is also the 6th row with amount 75 for the same user satisfying the date condition. Shouldn't that also be a part of it

Comment: I meant the 5th row.

Comment: @Abishek date of that 5th row is 1st October while the two 100 rows are at 30 September; as per the problem statement and used logic in the query, first priority is to lower date rows..

Comment: But the date condition is `<= '2019-10-31'`. Shouldn't that include the 5th row? This date is from the initial DBFiddle you setup. Changing the dates should still get the desired results right?