# How can I get the date where the balance reaches less than or equal to 0?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have a **credits** table where I'm trying to get the date where each positive entry has been exhausted:

| id | amount | user_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7280 | 2500 | 8282 | 2020-07-09 10:03:01 |
| 7472 | -2500 | 8282 | 2020-07-14 12:55:46 |
| 7473 | 2500 | 8282 | 2020-07-14 12:56:12 |
| 22491 | 3000 | 8282 | 2020-12-20 13:55:30 |
| 23433 | 4000 | 8282 | 2020-12-27 14:33:59 |
| 60246 | 10000 | 8282 | 2021-08-17 14:31:20 |
| 73797 | -8370 | 8282 | 2021-11-10 00:03:14 |
| 82784 | 20000 | 8282 | 2021-12-23 10:57:38 |
| 82801 | 5000 | 8282 | 2021-12-23 13:03:03 |
| 82905 | -5000 | 8282 | 2021-12-25 00:00:07 |
| 82906 | -4820 | 8282 | 2021-12-25 00:00:07 |

I've come up with a query using session variables but I can't seem to understand why it's not working as expected.

#### Query 1

```sql
select
    credits.id,
    credits.amount,
    credits.created_at,
    (
        select
            c.created_at
        from (
            select 
                t.id, 
                t.user_id, 
                t.amount, 
                t.created_at,
                (
                    case
                        when (t.amount > 0 and t.created_at > credits.created_at) then null
                        when @total <= 0 then @total
                        else @total := @total + t.amount                   
                    end
                ) as total
            from credits as t
            cross join (select @total := credits.amount) AS variables_initialization
            where
                t.id != credits.id
                and t.user_id = credits.user_id
            order by t.created_at, t.id
         ) AS c
         where
             c.total is not null
             and c.total <= 0
             and c.created_at >= credits.created_at
         limit 1
    ) as exhausted_at
from credits
where
    credits.amount > 0
    and credits.user_id = 8282;
```

#### Result

This is the result of my query:

| id | amount | created_at | exhausted_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7280 | 2500 | 2020-07-09 10:03:01 | 2020-07-14 12:55:46 |
| 7473 | 2500 | 2020-07-14 12:56:12 | 2021-11-10 00:03:14 |
| 22491 | 3000 | 2020-12-20 13:55:30 | 2021-11-10 00:03:14 |
| 23433 | 4000 | 2020-12-27 14:33:59 | 2021-11-10 00:03:14 |
| 60246 | 10000 | 2021-08-17 14:31:20 | 2021-11-10 00:03:14 |
| 82784 | 20000 | 2021-12-23 10:57:38 | 2021-12-25 00:00:07 |
| 82801 | 5000 | 2021-12-23 13:03:03 | 2021-12-25 00:00:07 |

As you can see, the `exhausted_at` for `23433` is returning `2021-11-10 00:03:14` instead of the expected `2021-12-25 00:00:07`. The balance should've still been positive for that record as of November 10th with `2500 + 3000 + 4000 - 8370 = 1130`.

However, if I try to run the same query by replacing the where clause by `where credits.id = 23433;`, the query returns the correct result.

| id | amount | created_at | exhausted_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23433 | 4000 | 2020-12-27 14:33:59 | 2021-12-25 00:00:07 |

I've inspired my query from the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58200916/5556440

---

### Update

I've tried to use window functions with the running total as suggested by @Barmar but I'm still not able to get my desired output.

```sql
select
    credits.id,
    credits.amount,
    credits.created_at,
    credits.running_total,
    (
        select c.created_at
        from credits as c
        where
            c.user_id = credits.user_id
            and c.amount < 0
            and abs(c.amount) >= running_total
            and c.created_at >= credits.created_at
        limit 1
    ) as exhausted_at
from (
    select
        c.id,
        c.amount,
        c.user_id,
        c.created_at,
        sum(amount) over (partition by c.user_id order by c.created_at) as running_total
    from credits as c
) as credits
where
    credits.amount > 0
    and credits.user_id = 8282
order by credits.created_at;
```

#### Result

| id | amount | created_at | running_total | exhausted_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7280 | 2500 | 2020-07-09 10:03:01 | 2500 | 2020-07-14 12:55:46 |
| 7473 | 2500 | 2020-07-14 12:56:12 | 2500 | 2021-11-10 00:03:14 |
| 22491 | 3000 | 2020-12-20 13:55:30 | 5500 | 2021-11-10 00:03:14 |
| 23433 | 4000 | 2020-12-27 14:33:59 | 9500 | 2022-01-26 00:12:35 |
| 60246 | 10000 | 2021-08-17 14:31:20 | 19500 |  |
| 82784 | 20000 | 2021-12-23 10:57:38 | 31130 |  |
| 82801 | 5000 | 2021-12-23 13:03:03 | 36130 |  |

Comment: Since you're using MySQL 8.x, you should use window functions rather than session variables.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not too familiar with window functions. Do you have an example that I can work from to accomplish what I need?

Comment: https://www.databasestar.com/sql-running-total/

Comment: @Barmar Can you have a look at my update please?  I've tried to use the running total but I can't seem to understand how that will get what I need. Because the running total for my 23433 is 9500, I thought that I could get the first date where the negative amount is greater than my running total. However, I realized that it won't work since the exhausted date might be divided in multiple batches.

Comment: Balance is typically stored in a denormalised manner to avoid queries like this....

Answer (score 0):

You could get it using analytic functions and case expressions. Here is one option to solve it. Sample data slightly changed as it is not clear what you want to do when balance is less than zero two or more rows one after another:

```sql
/*    S a m p l e    D a t a :   */
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS CREDITS;
Create Temporary Table CREDITS(ID INT,  AMOUNT DECIMAL(14, 2),  USER_ID INT,    CREATED_AT DATETIME);

INSERT INTO CREDITS Select 7280,    2500,   8282,   '2020-07-09 10:03:01';
INSERT INTO CREDITS Select 7472,    -2500,  8282,   '2020-07-14 12:55:46';
INSERT INTO CREDITS Select 7473,    2500,   8282,   '2020-07-14 12:56:12';
INSERT INTO CREDITS Select 22491,   3000,   8282,   '2020-12-20 13:55:30';
INSERT INTO CREDITS Select 23433,   4000,   8282,   '2020-12-27 14:33:59';
INSERT INTO CREDITS Select 60246,   -10000, 8282,   '2021-08-17 14:31:20';
INSERT INTO CREDITS Select 73797,   -8370,  8282,   '2021-11-10 00:03:14';
INSERT INTO CREDITS Select 82784,   20000,  8282,   '2021-12-23 10:57:38';
INSERT INTO CREDITS Select 82801,   5000,   8282,   '2021-12-23 13:03:03';
INSERT INTO CREDITS Select 82905,   -5000,  8282,   '2021-12-25 00:00:07';
INSERT INTO CREDITS Select 82906,   -4820,  8282,   '2021-12-25 00:00:07';
```

... first create a cte to prepare your data ...

```sql
WITH
  grid as 
    ( Select   ID, AMOUNT, CREATED_AT, USER_ID, 
               Case When 
                       Sum(AMOUNT) Over(Partition By USER_ID Order By CREATED_AT
                                   Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) <= 0
                    Then ID 
               End as GRP_END,
               Sum(AMOUNT) Over(Partition By USER_ID Order By CREATED_AT
                           Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) as BALANCE
     From     CREDITS 
     Order By CREATED_AT
  )
```

```sql
/*    M a i n    S Q L     */
SELECT x.ID, x.AMOUNT, x.CREATED_AT, x.USER_ID, x.BALANCE, 
  CASE WHEN x.EXHAUSTED_AT Is Null OR x.GRP_END = ID 
       THEN
       Min(Case When x.EXHAUSTED_AT >= x.CREATED_AT 
                Then x.EXHAUSTED_AT 
           End)
             Over(Partition By x.USER_ID Order By x.CREATED_AT
                  Rows Between Current Row And Unbounded Following) 
  END as EXHAUSTED_AT
FROM   ( Select     ID, AMOUNT, CREATED_AT, USER_ID, BALANCE, GRP_END,
                    Case When GRP_END Is Not Null 
                         Then CREATED_AT 
                    End as EXHAUSTED_AT
         From       grid  ) x
ORDER BY x.USER_ID, x.CREATED_AT
```

```sql
/*      R e s u l t :
ID           AMOUNT CREATED_AT          USER_ID     BALANCE EXHAUSTED_AT
---------- -------- ------------------- --------- --------- -------------------
7280        2500.00 2020-07-09 10:03:01 8282        2500.00 2020-07-14 12:55:46
7472       -2500.00 2020-07-14 12:55:46 8282           0.00 2020-07-14 12:55:46
7473        2500.00 2020-07-14 12:56:12 8282        2500.00 2021-08-17 14:31:20
22491       3000.00 2020-12-20 13:55:30 8282        5500.00 2021-08-17 14:31:20
23433       4000.00 2020-12-27 14:33:59 8282        9500.00 2021-08-17 14:31:20
60246     -10000.00 2021-08-17 14:31:20 8282        -500.00 2021-08-17 14:31:20
73797      -8370.00 2021-11-10 00:03:14 8282       -8870.00 2021-11-10 00:03:14
82784      20000.00 2021-12-23 10:57:38 8282       11130.00 
82801       5000.00 2021-12-23 13:03:03 8282       16130.00 
82905      -5000.00 2021-12-25 00:00:07 8282       11130.00 
82906      -4820.00 2021-12-25 00:00:07 8282       6310.00                      */
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it is not clear what you want to do when balance is less than zero two or more rows one after another"?

Comment: I've tested your query with my actual data and I'm not getting my desired output.

Comment: @ChinLeung Maybe you could provide the data that fails and explain the logic for border cases and exceptions. This answer finds zeros and minus balances and group the data in between. Does this sample data works ok or not.

Comment: It doesn't work because your balance goes negative where in my case it shouldn't. The case that wasn't working for my query is the id `23433`. The `exhausted_at` should've been `2021-12-25 00:00:07` but my query is returning `2021-11-10 00:03:14` instead. The reason why it should be in December is because the running total is 9500, and in November, we're removing 8370, which exhausted both the 7473 and 22491 but the 23433 is not fully exhausted until Demcember's removal of 5000.

Comment: @ChinLeung You missed that I changed 60246 to minus 10K ('Sample data slightly changed') because **1. Your data gives just 1 zero balance (7472) with no further zero nor minus balances at all  **2. Wanted to test multiple exhautions  **3. Wanted to ask what if there are two or more minuses one after another as in above changed data!!! With your data balance forr 2343 is 9500 and never exhausted.  You can see it here: https://dbfiddle.uk/6o6xWUAA ...